# Is it fine to call activity functions from private methods in a Durable Function orchestrator?

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions

Is it ok to call activity functions from private methods in a Durable Function orchestrator, or should that be avoided? Here's an example:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(OrchFunc))]
public async Task OrchFunc(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context,
    ILogger logger) {
    var myParameter = context.GetInput<string>();
    // Any issue with doing this with the way checkpoints work?
    var result = await MyPrivateFunc(context, myProperty);
}

private async Task<bool> MyPrivateFunc(
    DurableOrchestrationContext context,
    string myParameter) {
    return result = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>(nameof(MyActivityFunc), myParameter);
}
```

Keep in mind this is a simple example to clarify the question. I am already aware that it *could* be called directly from the orchestration function and thereby skip the private function. I'm not looking to see if it makes sense here, but rather just seeking to understand if there would be unintended side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you've probably moved on from this issue, but for anyone else seeking this out, yes this should work fine.  The `context` will be passed by reference so it will still be the one calling the activity function.  Note, however, that the restrictions on orchestrations will still apply to the private method, so no `await`ing anything called by something other than the `context`.